# Swift Not Equals, Forced Unwrap, and Whitespace

Tags: swift, syntax, swift2

I've been enjoying Swift for a while now, but I found one syntax that is incredibly problematic.

Start with the assumption that:

```
let foo : String = ""
```

This is a fairly simple check:

```
if foo!="value" {
```

But alas, it won't compile. The compiler complains about trying to unwrap a value that is not an optional. I then change that line to:

```
if foo != "value {
```

The compiler is happy and the code behaves as expected. This is a case of significant whitespace, and I'm not content with it. I suspect there are situations that this may compile and behave contrary to my intention. Is there an alternative syntax that I should be using to avoid this type of error?

Comment: Of course it thinks you are trying to unwrap foo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alternate syntax is to put spaces around infix operators. They are required. Without spaces, it is treated as a prefix or postfix operator. With spaces it is an infix operator. Swift is very consistent about this. I know you realize this is what's happening; I just don't believe there's any way around it, and any cure would be worse than the disease (I can't come up with any examples where this would likely lead to real-world bugs).

Swift will be forgiving if there is no conflict, and allow `1+1` for instance, but you shouldn't do this, either. I believe good Swift style is to just put the spaces in. Yes, it's a case of significant whitespace. The whitespace here is significant, just as you can't say `structFoo` when you mean `struct Foo`.

Comment: I'm aware of the requirement and how it's being treated. It simply seems error prone, much the same way C can be prone to error by confusing `if (foo=3) {` and `if (foo==3) {`.

Comment: While I disagree it's error prone (I'm having trouble designing a non-pathological case that would lead to incorrect behavior rather than just a syntax error), it wouldn't change anything if it were. There is no other habitual syntax you could use that wouldn't be much worse (you could replace `!=` with a function `notEqual()`, but that would be crazy). Parentheses won't help for instance. You must put in the spaces. Do you have an example where lack of spaces *would* lead to a semantic rather than syntactic error?

Comment: I definitely get the general instinct to build style habits that avoid bugs. It's a great goal. I just don't think it helps at all in this case because any solution (other than just cultivating the habit of putting in spaces, which luckily ports nicely to other languages) would be far worse than the problem IMO.